# Why isn't Flask getting the proper datetime.now into sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

In my Flask app, I have an issue where on a production server, `datetime.now()` is always inserting '2020-02-05' into my sqlite's 'date_posted' field.  The system time is accurate, so I have no idea where it's getting this date.  If I copy the app to another system, and run it, there are no issues.  I guess my question is, where in the path of system time, python retrieving the system time, and Flask passing the information to sqlite, would I begin trying to diagnose this issue?  Are there any permissions in this trail, that may be interfering.

System details, and code:  Ubuntu 18.04; nginx; sqlite

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(130), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now())
    ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"
```

Comment: default=datetime.now instead of default=datetime.now(). Currently it has as a default the date and time the server was started.

Comment: Thank you!  If you like to post that as an answer, I'd be glad to accept it.